# Understanding "Request Header is too large"

Tags: java, http, tomcat, http-headers

I am getting this error in Tomcat

```
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request header is too large
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseHeaders(Http11InputBuffer.java:583)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:703)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I want to understand the text `further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level`. Does this means the parsing errors will be suppressed for some time frame OR its only for that specific request. Could anyone give me authoritative source of this meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly as the message says. All further instances of this error will be logged at the DEBUG level. Not for that request and not for a period of time. From now until the end of time. Or the next time the server is restarted, whichever comes first.

You can see that in the source code here on line 1144:
https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/7.0.x/java/org/apache/coyote/http11/AbstractHttp11Processor.java

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was looking for.